# Is parallel HTTP connection limit applicable for internal web service call?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

My web application is making a call to an internal webservice for user authentication purpose and this is per request basis. 
Now as there is a limitation for parallel HTTP connection per domain, will it affect my application if it servs mutltiple requests per second. Or this limit is only applicable to browser based requests.

Answer (score 0):

That limit also applies to server processes although the default limit is higher - it allows [10 connections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit.aspx).

If you need you can still override that limit in code

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 200;
```

Comment: Is this limit also applicable if call is made using - `HttpWebRequest`

Comment: yes, it is applicable to all HTTP requests made in your application.